# How to invoke a method (reflection) with a not generic parameter?

Tags: java, android, reflection, invoke

I have a little problem.
I am developing an Android applikation. 
There you can dynamicly load classes from other applications (packages).
First of all, i do not want to "hack" an third-party app, i want to try to build up plugins for my own app.
So what do i have?

2 Test applications and 1 library which is in both apps included.

So the code for app1:

```
package com.ftpsynctest.app1;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.syncoorp.ftpsyncx.commons.SyncFile;
import dalvik.system.PathClassLoader;
public class App1Activity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        SyncFile f = new SyncFile("bla");
        String classname = "com.ftpsynctest.app2.classcall";
        String classpath = getApk("com.ftpsynctest.app1") + ":" + getApk("com.ftpsynctest.app2");
        PathClassLoader myClassLoader = new dalvik.system.PathClassLoader(classpath, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
        try {
            Class c = Class.forName(classname, true, myClassLoader);
            for (Method m : c.getDeclaredMethods()) {
                System.out.println("Method: " + m.getName());
                for (Type t : m.getGenericParameterTypes()) {
                    System.out.println(" - type: " + t.toString());
                }
                m.invoke(c.newInstance(), new Object[] {
                    new com.syncoorp.ftpsyncx.commons.SyncFile("bla")
                });
                break;
            }
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        catch (InvocationTargetException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        catch (InstantiationException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    private String getApk(String packageName) {
        try { return this.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0).sourceDir;}
        catch (NameNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        return "";
    }
}
```

So i want to create the class ***com.ftpsynctest.app2.classcall*** and call the method ***modify*** with a parameter of type ***com.syncoorp.ftpsyncx.commons.SyncFile***.

My app2 code:

```
package com.ftpsynctest.app2;
import com.syncoorp.ftpsyncx.commons.SyncFile;
public class classcall {
    public SyncFile modify(SyncFile file) {
        file.change_date = 123;
        return file;
    }
}
```

I first installed app2 to **provide** the class to app1.
After that succeed i started app1.

My Output:

**01-10 22:21:48.804: INFO/System.out(4681): Method: modify

01-10 22:21:48.809: INFO/System.out(4681):  - type: class com.syncoorp.ftpsyncx.commons.SyncFile**

So for now it looks good. the parameter type of the found method is  **com.syncoorp.ftpsyncx.commons.SyncFile**
and my provided one is the same.

But i get the following error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch  
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)  
      at com.ftpsynctest.app1.App1Activity.onCreate(App1Activity.java:44)  
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)  
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)  
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)  
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)  
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)  
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)  
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)  
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)  
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)  
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)  
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

But why? my output tells me that it is SyncFile and i put SyncFile to the invoke command.
Whats the problem there?
Can it be that compiling app2 creates a class from SyncFile which is different from the compiled app1 ? if yes, why ? the SyncFile class is the same physical class within my "commons" library which both projects share.

Anybody has a solution or answer?

Comment: You have a very big repro for what you call a small problem. Try to reduce the code to the smallest size with which you can reproduce the problem. In all likelihood you will yourself find out the error. If not, someone else here will explain it very quickly.

Comment: why should i reduce code? This code is exactly that what i need. it is reduced as much as it can be, because everything else will force me to write just 1 app but that is not what i want. it is important that the things works if i have 2 different apps within android. The only part which i could remove is the catch to Exception and not the 5

Answer (score 1):

There may be two identically named classes `SyncFile` visible to different classloaders in this case. Even if the classes are named exactly the same, in the same package, even with the same byte code they will be considered *different* classes by the VM because they come from different locations (classloaders).

At runtime, the identity of a class is defined by its package, its name *and* the classloader instance that loaded it. It is expected that every class can only be found/loaded by exactly *one* classloader. If that is not the case, the result will vary based upon which classloader is in effect when the class is accessed.

`new com.syncoorp.ftpsyncx.commons.SyncFile` will probably use the class loaded by and associated with the app's local classloader whereas the called method expects the version associated with `myClassLoader`. Since both classloaders know the 'same' class (identified by package+class name), but each one only knows *one* of them, from the JVM's perspective, they are two different classes.

You could try and create your `SyncFile` instance via reflection from the `SyncFile` class loaded by `myClassloader`, i.e.

```
Class sfClass = Class.forName("com.syncoorp.ftpsyncx.commons.SyncFile", true, myClassLoader);
Object param = sfClass.newInstance("bla"); // param must be Object because the 'local' SyncFile is not the same as the SyncFile represented by sfClass!
```

Note that you will face this problem *everywhere* where your app and a 'plugin' exchange instances of *any* class they both contain, i.e. reflection everywhere. Consider if it's worth the hassle or if you want to resort to some better way, e.g. IPC.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** This answer is incorrect. See below for a counterexample.

You've formatted your argument to `Method.invoke()` wrong. See the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29). Instead of passing a single Object[] array of all arguments, you just pass multiple arguments to invoke. That's what the `Object... args` notation means: the method accepts any number of Objects.

For your example, changing

```
m.invoke(c.newInstance(), new Object[] {
                new com.syncoorp.ftpsyncx.commons.SyncFile("bla")
            });
```

to

```
m.invoke(c.newInstance(), new com.syncoorp.ftpsyncx.commons.SyncFile("bla"));
```

should fix the problem.

---

Counterexample:

Refl.java:

```
package com.drfloob.so;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class Refl {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class c = Class.forName("com.drfloob.so.Refl2", true, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
            for (Method m : c.getDeclaredMethods()) {
                System.out.println("Method: " + m.getName());
                for (Type t : m.getGenericParameterTypes()) {
                    System.out.println(" - type: " + t.toString());
                }
                m.invoke(c.newInstance(), "test 1");
                m.invoke(c.newInstance(), new Object[] {"test 2"});
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Refl2.java:

```
package com.drfloob.so;

public class Refl2 {
    public Refl2() {
        System.out.println(Refl2.class);
    }

    public void doStuff(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's probably not the case. You can use an array as an argument for vararg.

Comment: You are correct. I must misunderstand the `...` notation. I coded up a non-android version and it works either way. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Yep its not the solution, tried with m.invoke(c.newInstance(), new com.syncoorp.ftpsyncx.commons.SyncFile("bla")); but didn't work, anybody has a solution?